# JavaScript Regex - Replace all word characters except word characters between character X and character Y

Tags: javascript, regex

Using JavaScript and regular expression, the method example `string.replace(/[\w]/g, "*")` replaces word characters with *.

Example:

```
John &amp; Sandy went to the market.
```

Becomes:

```
**** &***; ***** **** ** *** ******.
```

I want to do this except we want to avoid replacing characters inside "&" and ";" that are not separated by spaces.

Example:

```
&nbsp;John &amp; Sandy are awesome & rock; They are also weird.
```

Becomes:

```
&nbsp;**** &amp; ***** *** ******* & ****; **** *** **** *****.
```

My regex is weak and I am having a pretty hard time figuring this out. Reading other solutions also proved difficult. I am pretty sure this can be done in one regex pattern.

It also helps me if you can explain what exactly is going on in the regex pattern.

Bonus points if you can limit what sequence of characters can be within "&" and ";".

Comment: Have you considered HTML-parsing this string first, so that those entities are replaced by their corresponding characters? Then, you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: ^^ Seems like an XY problem. Underscore has an `unescape` method. [Check source](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1063).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, I can't consider this option. I must keep the text as it is, as it will be used later. This would be trying to solve a different problem.

Comment: Escaping and unescaping HTML entities is trivial, and will make everything simpler... What problem are you trying to solve exactly that you can't do this?

Comment: If I escape and then unescape, I lose any entities that were not in their original format. Like the ampersand before the word "rock".

Comment: My question then is why isn't the ampersand before "rock" escaped while the others are?

Comment: This is an example and I needed to show an ampersand and a semicolon broken by a space character. A poor example perhaps. Maybe if I threw in some code words in their instead it would make more sense. Imagine there could be anything in the string. Don't limit it to how you are suppose to render text as an html page, rather we are just parsing pure strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'&nbsp;John &amp; Sandy are awesome & rock; They are also weird.'.replace(
    /(&[^\s;]*;)|\w/g, function(a, b) {
    return b || '*'; });
```

The result:

```
&nbsp;**** &amp; ***** *** ******* & ****; **** *** **** *****.
```

Tried and works for me in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Clever solution! I believe an alternative form of the bracketed part would be `(&\S+?;)`, a minimal (non-greedy) match for non-space characters. Not sure which one will be the more efficient.